# Dropbox chooser : get content of the file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dropbox, dropbox-api

I use dropbox chooser in an HTML5 application and the API don't give you the file itself , it give the direct link to download the file. Something like : "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/ydld54fs5sford8/myFolder/myFile.csv".

How can I manage to download this file in javascript to get a file object and then read the content of this file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a standard AJAX call. For example, using jQuery:

```
$.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/...', function (data) {
    console.log(data); // <-- this will log the contents of the file
});
```

**EDIT**

Make sure you're using a *direct* link (one that looks like `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/...`), not a *preview* link (which points to an HTML page on `www.dropbox.com`).

Comment: This answer has been recently downvoted. If someone thinks things have changed (or can verify this still works), please add more info here. Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but I think version 1 has been retired.  Trying a link now appears to give an html file wrapped around the file contents.

Comment: I just checked. This is still working fine. If you're getting an HTML file, you're probably using a preview link instead of a direct link. (A preview link does *not* look like `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/...`.)

Comment: To get a download link from a preview link, do I just change `www` to `dl`?  Because I've spent the last week trying to figure that part out, and it doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere.

Comment: No, just pass `linkType: 'direct'` in your Chooser options. (See the documentation here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser).